# RCaller & RQuantlib error in java

Tags: programming, r, quantlib

I am receiving the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" rcaller.exception.RCallerExecutionException: RExecutable is not defined. Please set this variable to full path of R executable binary file.`

This being said, I have tested RCaller separately and have had it work (basic 1+1 example).

The code I am trying to run in Java is the following:

```
        public void computeImpliedVol(siteCall.reqObj rO) {
            try {
                double price;
                String modCP=callPut.contains("P")?"put":"call";
                SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("########");

                Date dMat = sf.parse(df.format(maturity));
                Date dt;
                double diff;
                caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/bin/Rscript");

                String command;


                for (Double d : hTimeSeries.keySet()) {
                    caller.addRCode("library(RQuantLib)");
                    dt = sf.parse(df.format(d));
                    diff=(dMat.getTime()-dt.getTime())/(60.0*60.0*1000.0*24.0)/365.0;
                    if (longShort > 0) {
                        price = hTimeSeries.get(minDate).ask;
                    } else {
                        price = hTimeSeries.get(minDate).bid;
                    }
                    command = "EOImpVol<-EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility(\"" + modCP + "\"," 
                           + price + "," + rO.requestObject.get(d).hAClose + "," + strike + ",0,.03," + 
                             diff + ",.2)";
                     caller.addRCode(command);
                     caller.runAndReturnResultOnline("EOImpVol");
                     double rDbl[]=caller.getParser().getAsDoubleArray("EOImpVol");
                     rDbl=rDbl;
                }
            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(optionDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        }
```

If I try to run the `command` in R I get:

```
        > EOImpVol<-EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility("put",1.9,21.18,21.0,0,.03,0.10410958904109589,.2)
        > EOImpVol
        $impliedVol
        [1] 0.7518471

        $parameters
   $parameters$type
        [1] "put"

        $parameters$value
        [1] 1.9

        $parameters$underlying
        [1] 21.18

        $parameters$strike
        [1] 21

        $parameters$dividendYield
        [1] 0

        $parameters$riskFreeRate
        [1] 0.03

        $parameters$maturity
        [1] 0.1041096

        $parameters$volatility
        [1] 0.2


        attr(,"class")
        [1] "EuropeanOptionImpliedVolatility" "ImpliedVolatility"
```

So I am assuming it works fine. Is something obvious occurring that I do not realize being new to this?

Thank you very much

Comment: This seems to be a programming only question. Consider moving to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Already [asked on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17538489/rcaller-rquantlib-error-in-java) before cross-posting here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think this mistake. caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.2/bin/Rscript");

you try to use backslash between word. caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\i386\Rscript");